# Strange duplicated answers

Tags: discussion, answers, low-quality-posts, duplicate-answers, duplicate-user

[ToAscii/ToUnicode in a keyboard hook destroys dead keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964614/toascii-tounicode-in-a-keyboard-hook-destroys-dead-keys)

This looks like a perfectly valid question, for a problem I'm having myself, but the answers are weird:

- The top rated answer is pure nitpick and doesn't address the problem.
- [Blue Eyes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/437723/blue-eyes) and [Ojos Azules](https://stackoverflow.com/users/606453/ojos-azules) ("blue eyes" in Spanish) have answered the exactly same thing, but one in English and the other in Spanish (later edited to English too).
- [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11324474/252218) is the same spirit as Blue Eyes'/Ojos Azules', repeated two years later.

I don't even know where to start flagging/editing/voting this mess. What should I do in this sort of situation?

(also, can somebody take a look into the [Blue Eyes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/437723/blue-eyes)/[Ojos Azules](https://stackoverflow.com/users/606453/ojos-azules) thing?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martin doesn't seem to be related to the other two, but Blue Eyes and Ojos Azules are both unregistered accounts coming from the same IP. Neither has any activity outside that question either, although that doesn't necessarily mean much since unregistered accounts are pretty easy to lose access to.

In any case, I removed the newer duplicate answer from Ojos Azules, but left Martin's up. I don't think there's anything else to be done here, unless you feel like throwing some votes around. How you vote, though, is entirely up to you.